# How to fix "Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)"

Tags: gnome-terminal

I am an Ubuntu user and I got this error.

The error is called: `Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

I'm using Ubuntu version 18.04 and i ran into this unexpectedly.

Hope you can help me!

EDIT: So I want to try to install nodejs and git and it showed the error then I did `sudo apt update` and also did `sudo apt upgrade` and it's telling me `unmet dependencies` and it told me to try `sudo apt --fix-broken install` and when I tried that it showed the error. I hope you can help me again.

EDIT_2: It told me to install `gsignond` and it failed

Comment: Error Code (1) simply means that some subprocess or script (not dpkg itself) had some kind of failure. It's a bit like saying "my bike is making a funny noise" -- insufficient information to help you. Please edit your question to show us the complete input you tried and the complete output that resulted. You may not understand all the cryptic output, but we do.

Comment: That's not complete input nor complete output. That's a summary. You are up to "my bike makes a funny noise when I ride it" -- still too vague.